# STL containers - How are unique key values determined?

Tags: c++, stl

In STL containers, like `map` and `set` - How the unique key is determined for user-defined types?

In C#, this is done by overriding `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A map, for example, takes 4 parameters as its template arguments. Most of the time, developers use just 2 of them i.e. the `Key` type and the `Value` type. But, one can also provide a functor that compares objects of the `Key` type (whatever type it would be).

From cplusplus.com:

> **Compare**: Comparison class: A class that takes two arguments of the key type and returns a bool. The expression comp(a,b), where comp is
>   an object of this comparison class and a and b are key values, shall
>   return true if a is to be placed at an earlier position than b in a
>   strict weak ordering operation. This can either be a class
>   implementing a function call operator or a pointer to a function (see
>   constructor for an example). This defaults to less, which returns
>   the same as applying the less-than operator (a

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/

It is true for almost all cases (when using  for sorting, or for any other container) and this principle holds across quite a few languages and platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Is the most simple case, it's determined by `Key1 < Key2`. That's to say, by an applicable `operator<`. There's no need for `Equals`. If `(!(Key1 < Key2)) && (!(Key2 < Key1))` (neither key is smallest), then they're considered equal. For practical purposes, this is wrapped in the `std::less<Key>` template.

If you want another order, all ordered STL containers take a *predicate*. This is an object that defines an `bool operator()(Key, Key)` member to implement a strict weak ordering on keys. That means `Pred(a,b) && Pred(b,c)` implies `Pred(a,c)`, `Pred(a,a)` must be false, and `Pred(a,b) && Pred(b,a)` must also be false. In other words, it must be a "normal" ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Seems like I'm talking about something slightly different here, but I guess I'll just leave it since it seems to be what you're talking about in C#.

You still need to implement your own hash-function and eq-function, you just do it differently. There's different ways of doing so, one for instance is to define a class with operator() to return a certain value etc, then when you define your map you say `map<YourClass, YourHashClass, YourEqClass, ...>`

Comment: std::map and std::set are not hash containers. What you say applies to std::unordered_map, std::unordered_set (and multi- versions) from c++11.

Comment: Yes, it would seem so. I suppose compare is enough for the "regular" stl "map", my bad.

Comment: std::map and std::set are ordered, so simple "is equal" comparison won't do. the standard requires "less-than" comparison. This can be a comparison functor or function, or the type itself can have an operator<.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is unclear what containers do you need. If you talk about hashes, then use std::unordered_map and see [Defining a hash function in TR1 unordered_map inside a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434484/defining-a-hash-function-in-tr1-unordered-map-inside-a-struct)  If you need map or set, you can set order using operator< [c++ less operator overload, which way to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016880/c-less-operator-overload-which-way-to-use)